# Make product featured/not featured with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to make function for featured/not featured product in Laravel 4.2 but I get error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()

This is my controller function

```
public function featuredProduct() {

    $product_featured_id = Input::get('featured');

    $product = Product::where('product_id', $product_featured_id);

    Product::where('featured', 1)->update(['featured' => 0]); // make all other products featured -> 0

    $product->featured = 1;
    $product->save();
    return Redirect::to('/admin/products')->with('message', 'Product marked as featured!');
}
```

And this is the form in the view

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => '/admin/products/feature', 'method' => 'post']) }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="featured">
            <option value="0">Remove from Featured</option>
                @foreach($products as $featured)

                    <option value="{{ $featured->product_id }}" {{ $featured->featured == 1 ? "selected" : ""}}>{{ $featured->title }}</option>
                @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Make Product Featured</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

In the table with products I have column which is save `1` for featured product and `0` for not featured product.

What I missing here?

update:

```
public function featuredProduct() {

    $product_featured_id = Input::get('featured');

    if($product_featured_id == 0)
    {
        Product::where('featured', 1)->update(['featured' => 0]); // make all other products featured -> 0
    }
    else 
    {
        $product = Product::where('product_id', $product_featured_id)->first();
        Product::where('featured', 1)->update(['featured' => 0]); // make all other products featured -> 0

        $product->featured = 1;
        $product->save();
    }

    return Redirect::to('/admin/products')->with('message', 'Product marked as featured!');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `->first()` method call:

```
$product = Product::where('product_id', $product_featured_id)->first();
```

In this case, you'll get an object and not an instance of Query Builder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works if I choose product to be featured. But if I choose option `Remove from Featured` got this error `ErrorException: Creating default object from empty value`

Comment: I've updated my question with how I've made it. Seems to work but is it good approach? Can this be optimized or no?